# Lua_dobufffer equivalent in lua 5.1

Tags: lua

What is the equivalent for `lua_dobuffer` in lua5.1 ?

In la 4.0 `lua_dobuffer` is declared like this:

```
int lua_dobuffer (lua_State *L, const char *buff,
                         size_t size, const char *name);
```

But in lua5.1 i can't find an equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`luaL_loadbuffer`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_loadbuffer) has the same signature as `lua_dobuffer` but it doesn't run the loaded string it just loads it into a chunk which needs to then be called. So you will need to handle that bit yourself.

> ```
> int luaL_loadbuffer (lua_State *L,
>                  const char *buff,
>                  size_t sz,
>                  const char *name);
> ```
>
> Loads a buffer as a Lua chunk. This function uses [lua_load](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_load) to load the chunk in the buffer pointed to by `buff` with size `sz`.
>
> This function returns the same results as [lua_load](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_load). `name` is the chunk name, used for debug information and error messages.

Comment: Additionally see how `luaL_dostring` and `luaL_dofile` are defined in [`lauxlib.h`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lauxlib.h.html).